# C macro with {}

Tags: c, macros, compiler-errors

I have defined the following struct in C:

```
typedef struct point{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} Point;
typedef Point Vector;
```

and the following macro:

```
#define sub(p1,p2)      {p1.x-p2.x,p1.y-p2.y,p1.z-p2.z}
```

That is used like this:

```
void fun(Point p0, Point p1){
    Vector u;
    u=sub(p1,p0);
}
```

From what I've read this should work, or maybe I'm missing something maybe even obvious... but I'm getting the following error that I don't understand what I'm supposed to look do:

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
```

So basically I just want to obtain the same as:

```
struct point u={p1.x-p0.x,p1.y-p0.y,p1.z-p0.z}
```

I really have no idea of what am I doing wrong...
Thank you.

[EDIT]
included some more function details so you can see where I think my mistake was. Not initializing with the variable declaration because after changing

```
Vector u;
u=sub(p1,p0);
```

to

```
Vector u=sub(p1,p0);
```

It works but I still don't understand why.

Comment: show all the code, the error is probably not in the snippet you are showing

Comment: Did you try to compile it without the macro, e.g. `Vector u={p1.x-p0.x,p1.y-p0.y,p1.z-p0.z};`?

Comment: yes I compiled without the macro and it works and I'm using gcc

Comment: It compiles with macro as well, you can see it at work [here](http://ideone.com/JqswX); maybe the error is elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the macro: the problem would persist even if you expand this macro by hand. The reason why this is failing is that initializer list in an assignment must be composed of *constant expressions*, so `p1.x` is not allowed.

If you are using C99, change your macro to use a [*compound literal*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.5), like this:

```
#define sub(p1,p2)      (Vector){p1.x-p2.x,p1.y-p2.y,p1.z-p2.z}
```

This will let you use the macro in assignments as well as in initializers.

Comment: I think it is a GCC extension which allows non constant initializers and [it does compile](http://ideone.com/Yero1) on GCC, but this may not be a portable way to do it; thus agree with your suggestion

Comment: When you say its not portable, you mean across compilers right?

Comment: actually this was also my first guess that `Vector u` was declared at file scope but the error message would probably be more explicit. I think the error is elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @Reonarudo: Yes I meant across compilers

Comment: @Reonarudo Now that I see your use case, the question looks a lot clearer. Please see the edit for a fix. Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/f6zbl) to a working example with an assignment that used to trigger the error without `(Vector)`.